# How to from one component set state another component in react native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, state

I have a problem. I want to set state another component from one component but I don't know how to do it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Component1: The component that you want to change the state from that.
>   
> Component2: The component that you want to change its state from
>   another component.

- If the the Component2 is child of the Component1, you can do this by
  passing new state as props to Component2.
- If the Component2 is the parent of Component1, you should do this by
  a function that is defined in the Component2 (this function change
  the state of Component2) and passed to Component1 as a prop.
- Otherwise you can use `redux` to manage the state and define a
  `mapStateToProps` function in Component2 to affect it by changing the
  state by Component1.